# Inserting into the Metor users collection in php

Tags: php, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to setup a sign up form for a Meteor app in php and then add the users to Meteor.users collection. I can get my data into the collection but it can't find my user in Meteor because I can't get the right syntax.

Here is how I am inserting the user info;

```
/*
This is what I need it to look like
 "emails" : [{
      "address" : "demo@demo.com",
      "verified" : false
    }]
*/

    try {
        $db = $mongoConn->xhTforp;
        $collection = $db->users;
        $user = array("username" => $_POST['username'], "emails" => array( "address" => $_POST['email'], "verified" => true ), "services" => array ( "password" =>  array( "srp" => "Meteor._srp.generateVerifier(".$_POST['password'].")" )));

        $collection->insert($user);
    } catch (MongoException $e) {
        die('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }

/*
Here what I get
"emails" : {
"address" : "demo@demo.com",
"verified" : true
},
"services" : {
 "password" : {
  "srp" : "Meteor._srp.generateVerifier(password)"
}
```

}

I can't figure out how to get that to use the `[{}]` syntax? (FYI, I have no idea what the password part does, it was something I found here)

Comment: Why are you trying to do it in PHP when it is already built out in js?

Comment: You could build an array of emails address, usinh array_push for example. As a general notice when inserting from php to mongodb for meteor, be careful with date format, and _id. Meteor use it's own generated ids, which is not ObjectId. As far as I known, inserting objectid (from Php: MongoId) as string is working.